# How to fetch multiple rows data one by one using SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `Employee`. Below is the table design.

`Employee` table:

```
+-----------+-------------+---------------+
|EmployeeID | EmployeeName|EmployeeContact|
+-----------+-------------+---------------+
|101        |   test1     |   9999999999  |
|102        |   test2     |   9999999999  |
|103        |   test3     |   9999999999  |
+-----------+-------------+---------------+
```

I would like loop based on `EmployeeID` and update `EmployeeName` based on `EmployeeID`.

How to do it? Please help me to solve this task.

Comment: please explain why you want to do this one row at a time and how you plan to update the employee name. there will likely be a better solution

Comment: As @Tanner said please explain more.

Comment: Please show the expected result

Answer (score 3):

Don't loop - use a **set-based** approach:

```
UPDATE dbo.Employee
SET EmployeeName = .......
```

You need to define and formulate *how* the update is supposed to happen (your question is very unclear on this point).

You might need to add a `WHERE` clause to the `UPDATE` in order not to update every row, and you might need to join to other tables as well.

Read all about the `UPDATE` command [in the **official** MSDN documentation on it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx) - it also has a lot of various examples how to do these kinds of things.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you:

```sql
DECLARE @curEmployee CURSOR;
DECLARE @iEmpID BigINT
DECLARE @vEmployeeName Varchar(50), @EmployeeContact Varchar(50)

BEGIN
    SET @curEmployee = CURSOR LOCAL READ_ONLY FAST_FORWARD FOR
    select EmployeeID,EmployeeName, EmployeeContact from dbo.Employee

    OPEN @curEmployee 
    FETCH NEXT FROM @curEmployee 
    INTO @iEmpID, @vEmployeeName, @EmployeeContact

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
    PRINT Cast (@iEmpID as Varchar(10)) + ' - ' +   @vEmployeeName + ' - ' +   @EmployeeContact

    -- Here Write the code based on @iEmpID

      FETCH NEXT FROM @curEmployee 
      INTO @iEmpID, @vEmployeeName, @EmployeeContact
    END

    CLOSE @curEmployee 
    DEALLOCATE @curEmployee
END
```